# giving short value's in if blocks and give them to another method in different activity

Tags: android

I've got a piece of code that gives short gridSize a value onclick(that's what I hope it does, if you see any mistakes please correct me). but for now it doesn't do anything yet...

the code that gives the short values:

```
public static short getGridSize(PuzzleActivity puzzleActivity, ImageButton view)  {
        if ( mIbtn3x3 == view) {
            String puzzle3 = "3";
            Short gridSize = Short.parseShort(puzzle3);
        } else if (mIbtn4x4 == view ) {
            String puzzle4 = "4";
            Short gridSize = Short.parseShort(puzzle4);
        } else if (mIbtn5x5 == view ) {
            String puzzle5 = "5";
            Short gridSize = Short.parseShort(puzzle5);
        }
        return Short.parseShort(PuzzleActivity.gridSize);
    }
```

the code that should receive the value (puzzle activity):

```
 createGameBoard(SizeSelection.getGridSize(this));
            break;
```

in the if block code : gridSize gets the following error : "gridSize cannot be resolved or is not a field".

in the PuzzleActivity code : .getGridSize gets the following error : "The method getGridSize(PuzzleActivity, ImageButton) in the type SizeSelection is not applicable for the arguments (PuzzleActivity)".

clearly I'm not a professional coder. please help me fixing this. thanks in advance ~olijf

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here. The first thing I'll cover is the compiler error.

It sounds like you are calling `getGridSize` wrong from your code, it wants you to pass in an `ImageButton` along with the activity.

Assuming your `ImageButton` is called `imageButton`, the code would look something like this (binding it to `view` so you can switch on it):

```
createGameBoard(SizeSelection.getGridSize(this, imageButton));
```

Inside `getGridSize` you're not resetting the gridSize variable but instead creating a new one inside each if/then block. You need to do something like this:

```
Short gridSize = -1;
if(mIbtn3x3 == view) {
    String puzzle3 = "3";
    gridSize = Short.parseShort(puzzle3);
}
else if(mIbtn4x4 == view) {
    String puzzle4 = "4";
    gridSize = Short.parseShort(puzzle4);
}
...
return Short.parseShort(gridSize);
```

But really you're doing a lot of unnecessary calls to `parseShort`. I would do something more like this:

```
public static short getGridSize(...) {
     switch(view) {
          case mIbtn3x3:
               return 3;
          case mIbtn4x4:
               return 4;
          case mIbtn5x5:
               return 5;
     }
}
```

Comment: the mIbtn3x3, 4x4, 5x5 are ImageButtons.

Answer (score 0):

First - variable range.
Java variable lives between brackets - {}
At this line:

```
return Short.parseShort(PuzzleActivity.gridSize);
```

You just have not declared static field "gridSize" in your class.
Do something like that:

```
static short getGridSize(){
private short gridSize;
if{...}
else if{...}
return gridSize;
}
```

Seccond error indicates that you call getGird() with wrong arguments (types) and use PuzzleActivity instead of ImageButton